# ServiceStack logging request body under load issue?

Tags: servicestack

Switched on request logging of body and in development it works fine.  Testing now under load and getting error in my log4net logs.

```
ERROR 17-10-2019 14:34:44 ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost [50] - ServiceBase<TRequest>::Service Exception System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'The stream with Id eacfc65d-dcfc-45dd-906b-ddbdb9dd025b and Tag  is disposed.'.
   at ServiceStack.Text.RecyclableMemoryStream.CheckDisposed() in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\RecyclableMemoryStream.cs:line 1393
   at ServiceStack.Text.RecyclableMemoryStream.set_Position(Int64 value) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\RecyclableMemoryStream.cs:line 1017
   at ServiceStack.StreamExtensions.ReadToEnd(MemoryStream ms, Encoding encoding) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\StreamExtensions.cs:line 363
   at ServiceStack.StreamExtensions.ReadToEnd(Stream stream, Encoding encoding) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\StreamExtensions.cs:line 442
   at ServiceStack.Host.NetCore.NetCoreRequest.GetRawBody() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\NetCore\NetCoreRequest.cs:line 207
   at RvRequestLogger.DbRequestLogger.CreateEntry(IRequest request, Object requestDto, Object response, TimeSpan requestDuration, Type requestType) in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/RvRequestLogger/DbRequestLogger.cs:line 129
   at RvRequestLogger.DbRequestLogger.Log(IRequest request, Object requestDto, Object response, TimeSpan elapsed) in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/RvRequestLogger/DbRequestLogger.cs:line 47
   at ServiceStack.HttpExtensions.EndHttpHandlerRequestAsync(IResponse httpRes, Boolean skipHeaders, Boolean skipClose, Func`2 afterHeaders) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\HttpExtensions.cs:line 121
   at ServiceStack.HttpResponseExtensionsInternal.WriteToResponse(IResponse response, Object result, StreamSerializerDelegateAsync defaultAction, IRequest request, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix, CancellationToken token) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\HttpResponseExtensionsInternal.cs:line 364
   at ServiceStack.Validation.ValidationFilters.RequestFilterAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, Object requestDto, Boolean treatInfoAndWarningsAsErrors) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Validation\ValidationFilters.cs:line 65
```

Now my DbRequestLogger line 129 is doing this, GetRawBody;

```
if (EnableRequestBodyTracking)
                    {
#if NETSTANDARD2_0
                        // https://forums.servicestack.net/t/unexpected-end-of-stream-when-uploading-to-aspnet-core/6478/6
                        if (!request.ContentType.MatchesContentType(MimeTypes.MultiPartFormData))
                        {
                            entry.RequestBody = request.GetRawBody();
                        }
#else
                        entry.RequestBody = request.GetRawBody();
#endif
                    }
```

This might be related to this post https://forums.servicestack.net/t/unexpected-end-of-stream-when-uploading-to-aspnet-core/6478/8

Any ideas?  Seems the request has passed us by at this point.

Comment: The Exception indicates the `BufferedStream` has already been disposed, if you can provide a stand-alone repro I can investigate, otherwise you can check whether you cab read from the buffered stream `((NetCoreRequest)request).BufferedStream.CanRead` in your logger to prevent the Exception and log the request of the request.

Comment: Perfect answer as always.

Comment: Some errors in the log.  ERROR 17-10-2019 20:42:44 ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteUtils [229] - Index was outside the bounds of the array. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvTypeSerializer.EatMapKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Int32& i) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\Jsv\JsvTypeSerializer.cs:line 296
   at ....

Comment: can happen if serialization format is invalid, if you provide a repro I can take a look.

Comment: Can't easily provide a repro, but something causing the request logger to fail and not log each request.  Bottom error is at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions.PopulateWithSqlReader[T](T objWithProperties, IOrmLiteDialectProvider dialectProvider, IDataReader reader, Tuple`3[] indexCache, Object[] values) in C:\BuildAgent\work\27e4cc16641be8c0\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions.cs:line 364

Comment: Switched in the standard ServiceStack CsvLogger instead.  All good.